# Convert Subclassed Speech Recognition Model to Tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow, keras, speech-recognition, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I have a subclassed Speech Recognition model ([link](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/eb340s2ab4sv0/qnet15)) with which I'd like to make inferences on my node.js server. I am trying to convert it using `tfjs` but because its a subclassed model I'm getting the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Saving the model to HDF5 format requires the model to be a Functional model or a Sequential model. It does not work for subclassed models, because such models are defined via the body of a Python method, which isn't safely serializable. Consider saving to the Tensorflow SavedModel format (by setting save_format="tf") or using `save_weights`.
```

I am following the [official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_keras), which doesn't count this scenario in. And surprisingly I couldn't find much info on the web apart from a [closed issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1556).

Any ideas on how to convert a Subclassed Model to `tensorflowjs`?

Comment: Don't save your model like this: `model.save("model.h5")`. Save in the SavedModel format like this: `model.save("target_directory")`.

Comment: I am feeding a `.pb` model to tensorflowjs_converter. If we're talking about python code I tried  `tensorflowjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, out)` as mentioned in the linked tutorial above

Comment: Please add the code where you have saved the model, and where you have loaded it and converted, to your question. It's a little bit hard to find out which variables you passed or what may be wrong.

Comment: I am simply following the official tutorial, linked above in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I was specifically trying to convert a speech recognition model (link above) and it seems that most such models aren't supported at the moment by [tfjs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter) (including [mozilla's deepspeech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech)).

It will specifically throw this error:

```
ValueError: Unsupported Ops in the model before optimization
AudioSpectrogram
```

The command used being in this case:

```
tensorflowjs_converter path/to/qnet15/ path/to/qnet15/converted/ --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_format=tfjs_graph_model
```

This error can be silenced, however, by adding the `--skip_op_check` flag to the above command. It will generated the expected `model.json` with its corresponding weight binaries after a bunch of warnings.

But, if you try inference @node, the same error occurs:

```
Promise {
  <rejected> TypeError: Unknown op 'AudioSpectrogram'. File an issue at https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues so we can add it, or register a custom execution with tf.registerOp()
```

The model is basically useless. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1728) for this feature since some years now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `model.save_weights()` as in the tutorial you should use the other option which is `model.save("my_model_dir")` and you can check here for [confirmation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_the_entire_model).

After saving the model directory you would want to convert it using the Tensorflowjs Converter

```
$ tensorflowjs_converter \
    --input_format=tf_saved_model \
    my_model_dir \ # input_path 
    converted_model # output_path
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, this is not what I was asking. I need to convert a Keras model to Tensorflow.js and not just generally save a model (editing the question to make it clearer)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. However, this deson't really change anything. I tried it and it throws same error as explained above.
The problem is that my model (Qnet15, linked above) is a custom model and hence it throws that error. Loading the model  in Keras and then saving it again doesn't make a difference. 
Or is there something I didn't understand in your answer?

Comment: @Bendemann are you passing in the directory and not the `model.pb`?